# What is the value of platform.system() in WINDOWS when system is booting?

Tags: python, windows, boot

I am specifically interested for preboot condition. 
Suppose windows system is in preboot state and I run platform.system() through some
preboot executable. What would be its value?

Comment: How are you running Python in a preboot situation? The answer will depend entirely on the Python interpreter and the environment it's running in.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your message. As I said environment is windows (specifically win server 2012). I converted python code to exe and running  it for some pre-boot hook ups which are required for encryption purpose. Would help if you can share some internal implementation of this function or any possible values during pre-boot?

Comment: It depends on how you converted the Python to an executable. If you used a tool like `py2exe` you'll need to ask the developers of that tool. I'm actually surprised that such a package runs correctly without the full operating system present -- I would imagine that many OS-level behaviors will simply not work at all, or work incorrectly, in such an environment.

Comment: AFAIK, platform.system() is implemented in terms of uname. Isn't it? Do you think py2exe will change implementation of platform.system() from *uname* to something else?. If it is so, I am more curious to know about it with real facts.

Comment: Also, you are right such package should n't work in preboot environment. Python documentation say's if value can't be fetched, it will return empty string.  Let me tell you many people/ world class products does such thing, they convert python code to executables and run in preboot time, but that's another topic to be discussed.